Random walk between two reflecting barriers
The question is from Feller's book "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications", chapter XIV, problem 11.
We have a 1-D symmetric, discrete and simple random walk in (0,a) interval with two barriers at 0 and a, and a starting point z between those two extremes. The probability that at nth step, the restricted random walk ends up at point x is $u_{z,n}(x)$. Also assume $v_{i,n}$ is the probability of reaching point i at the nth step, having started at origin in an unrestricted random walk.
(a) If both barriers are absorbing, then prove$$u_{z,n}(x) = \sum_k\{v_{x-z-2ka,n} - v_{x+z-2ka,n}\}$$
the summation extending over all integers.
(b) If both barriers are reflecting prove the above equation holds with minus replaced by plus and x+z replaced by x+z-1.
I don't have any problem proving the (a) part, the answer can be found in here, or alternatively you can check that the equation satisfies the corresponding difference equation and boundary conditions. My problem is for the (b) part, where solution should satisfy the difference equation:
$$u_{z,n+1}(x) = \frac{1}{2}(u_{z+1,n}(x) + u_{z-1,n}(x))$$ with boundary conditions: $u_{0,n}(x) = u_{1,n}(x)$ and  $u_{a,n}(x) = u_{a-1,n}(x)$. Also $u_{z,0}(x)$ equals zero for all z other than x, and equals one for z=x. If we proceed as the problem instructs us (replacing minus with plus etc.) we end up with:
$$u_{z,n}(x) = \sum_k\{v_{x-z-2ka,n} + v_{x+z-1-2ka,n}\}$$
The boundary condition is satisfied at lower barrier 0, but at the upper one a we have: $$u_{a,n}(x) = \sum_k\{v_{x-a-2ka,n} + v_{x+a-1-2ka,n}\}$$ which is not equal to $u_{a-1,n}(x)$ which is:
$$u_{a-1,n}(x) = \sum_k\{v_{x-a+1-2ka,n} + v_{x+a-2-2ka,n}\}$$
So if my reasoning is right, the proposed solution of the book is not correct (maybe a typo or somtething else). I tried an alternative interpretation of "replacing minus with plus", that is replacing all minuses in the subscripts, but still didn't satisfy the conditions. So what is the right answer for this question? If the book's answer is correct, where is the hole in my reasoning? Any approach, whether using combinatorics or difference equations is welcomed.

Feller is mistaken. The correct version for two reflecting barriers is
$$
u_{z,n}(x)=\sum_k(v_{x-z-2(\color{blue}{a-1})k,n}+v_{x+z-1-2(\color{blue}{a-1})k,n}).
$$
You can check that this satisfies all of the necessary boundary conditions:
$$
u_{0,n}(x)=u_{1,n}(x)\qquad u_{a,n}(x)=u_{a-1,n}(x)
\\
u_{z,n}(0)=u_{z,n}(1),\qquad u_{z,n}(a)=u_{z,n}(a-1)
$$
Note that time-reversal symmetry implies that $u_{z,n}(x)=u_{x,n}(z)$.
